# OpenGL Texture deallocation

Tags: opengl, sdl

I'm using SDL to create OpenGL context. When I create texture like this:

```
float *data = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)* SIZE * SIZE * 3);
for (long int i = 0; i < SIZE * SIZE * 3; i++)
{
    data[i] = 0;
}
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, GAMESIZE, GAMESIZE, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, data);
```

Do i need to deallocate data pointer before application closes or does SDL handle that?
I'm calling

```
SDL_Quit();
SDL_GL_DeleteContext(m_glContext);
```

in the end.

Comment: `glTexImage2D (...)` does not actually use the `data` pointer long-term. It copies image data from the memory pointed to and performs optional data conversion during this operation (pixel transfer). You are free to delete the storage pointed to immediately after this function returns. Only GL functions with ***Pointer*** in their name actually  use your pointer long-term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `malloc()`'d it, you gotta `free()` it.  That's independent of SDL and OpenGL.

`glTexImage2D()` only accesses `data` for the duration of the call, it doesn't take ownership of the pointer.

Comment: Thanks for straight answer, one more question, can I free it right after calling glTexImage2D?

Comment: Yep, OpenGL is done with the pointer as soon as `glTexImage2D()` returns.